# How to let touch events pass through to view below ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to place a map under another view, so that it can be revealed by scrolling the view on top up. **This gif should demonstrate:**
[image]

This implementation is done with a spacer below the actual content:

```
var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            //i want to tap this view...
            BackgroundMapCONTENTVIEW()
                .onTapGesture {
                    print("i wish i could be tapped")
                }
            //...but this ScrollView is getting all the user input
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                ScrollView {
                    ZStack {
                        Rectangle()
                            .accentColor(Color.white)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            .frame(width: proxy.size.width, height: proxy.size.height, alignment: .top)
                            .allowsHitTesting(false)
                        CompassCONTENTVIEW()
                            .frame(width: proxy.size.width, height: proxy.size.height, alignment: .top)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                        .frame(height: 450.0)
                        .opacity(0.0)
                        .disabled(true)
                        .allowsHitTesting(false)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see I have tried .allowsHitTesting(false) and .disabled(true). **But the ScrollView is currently getting all the touch events**.
What do I do?

Comment: Should you have to use ScrollView? what does it contain?

Comment: The scrolling is the intended design. Currently ScrollView contains  CompassCONTENTVIEW() and a Spacer()

Comment: ScrollView by default takes all the height. You are infact tapping on the ScrollView. Therefore, `onTapGesture` is not executed. Either make a custom scroll view or use a ScrollView with fixed height.

Comment: Making a `ScrollView` with fixed height will not let me scroll past said height. Then I would not be able to over scroll at the bottom and reveal the `Map` below.
And could you elaborate on the "custom `ScrollView`" idea? Thank you :)

Comment: What is the max height of CompassCONTENTVIEW? It is it more than the screen height?

Comment: The max height of `CompassCONTENTVIEW` equals screen height.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I suspect you're going to have to resort to a custom UIKit view wrapped in a `UIViewRespresentable`.  I've seen apps with a similar effect, but I don't recall the covered view being something to interact with.  In one case it was basically advertising (and covering the ad isn't very good advertising practice!), and in at least one other it was just a bit of decorative background.

Comment: This is an excellent question, and a common interface pattern now. What's the simple solution?